# Receiving partial payment of overseas loan/company purchase?

Tags: united-states, taxes, investing, international

We invested in buying a company in Africa and want to send money back to the U.S. as partial repayment on the money we invested.

What do we have to file, and what are the tax implications on the return of the money? This was our own money and are just paying ourselves back.

Answer (score 1):

Is it equity, or debt? Understanding the exact nature of one's investment (equity vs. debt) is critical.

When one invests money in a company (presumably incorporated or limited) by *buying* some or all of it — as opposed to *lending* money to the company — then one ends up owning *equity* (shares or stock) in the company. In such a situation, one is a *shareholder* — not a creditor.

As a shareholder, one is not generally owed a money debt just by having acquired an ownership stake in the company. Shareholders with company equity generally *don't* get to treat money received from the company as repayment of a loan — unless they also made a loan to the company and the payment is designated by the company as a loan repayment.

Rather, shareholders can receive cash from a company through one of the following sources:

- from **dividends**, a share of the company's profits declared and distributed to shareholders,
- through **the sale of shares**, whether back to the company or to someone else, or,
- by drawing **fees** or a **salary**, if one is also made a company director, manager, or employee.

"Loan repayment" isn't one of those options; it's only an option if one made a loan in the first place. Anyway, each of those ways of receiving money based on one's shares in a company has distinct tax implications, not just for the shareholder but for the company as well.

You should consult with a tax professional about the most effective way for you to repatriate money from your investment. Considering the company is established overseas, you may want to find somebody with the appropriate expertise.